# how to click on listview item that will tranfer me to website url?

Tags: android

I have a listview with items inside.
can anybody please help me to write a code that when I click on an item it will transfer me to website , 
for EX : a list of birds when I click on a bird it will give me the color of the bird.
thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("your link");  
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);  
    startActivity(launchBrowser);  
}
```

Add Internet permission to manifest

Comment: thanks for your help. now I got error : "The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type Activity "

Comment: on your activity extend OnListItemClick interface..you will get the above method and intilize this inside onCreate

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Uri url = Uri.parse("your link");  
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);  
            startActivity(intent); 

        }
    });
```